# How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning:

Tags: string, pandas

I am using ipython3 notebook and running the following command:

```
separ['RT'] = separ['text'].str.contains(r"^(?=.*\bRT\b\s@\b).*$", 
case=False) == True
```

The warning I get is as follows:

```
-c:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I have no idea what is means and how to handle this.

Comment: What is your code above `separ['RT'] = separ['text'].str.contains(r"^(?=.*\bRT\b\s@\b).*$", 
case=False) == True` ?

Comment: Can you add it to question?

Comment: I created separ from another dataframe as follows
`separ= tweets[tweets['TradeWar'] == True]`

Answer (score 0):

This type of error is usually a sign that Pandas has created a lightweight copy of a subset of a dataframe, which you then try to modify in place.

For example, suppose you had a dataframe which had a column of the integers 1..10, and created a selection of rows that were even:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({ 'int': range(10),
                        'label': [ 'x'+str(i) for i in range(10) ] })
sub = df[(df.int % 2) == 0]
```

The dataframe `sub` now contains:

```
0    x0
2    x2
4    x4
6    x6
8    x8
Name: label, dtype: object
```

However, `sub` is really only a view onto the memory footprint of the original dataframe, `df`. If we now try to modify `sub`:

```
sub.label = [ 'y' + str(j) for j in range(5) ]
```

We get the error message you've been seeing:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

If you want to avoid this, you may need to use the `.copy()` method:

```
newsub = df[(df.int % 2) == 0].copy()
newsub.label = [ 'y' + str(j) for j in range(5) ]
```

Comment: Thanks! It was bulls's eye hit. The `.copy()` was the exact thing needed.

Comment: Glad that it solved your problem. Can the question be marked as resolved? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in filtering:

```
separ = tweets[tweets['TradeWar'] == True]
```

What is same as:

```
separ = tweets[tweets['TradeWar']]
```

And need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
separ = tweets[tweets['TradeWar']].copy()
```

If you modify values in `separ` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`tweets`), and that Pandas does warning.

Also code shoud be simplify too:

```
separ['RT'] = separ['text'].str.contains(r"^(?=.*\bRT\b\s@\b).*$", case=False)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `==True` can be omitted because I need to filter only those tweets for which the value is true. This column `TradeWar` was created only as boolean response to some query. And has only two values as True and False .  I need only those tweets for which it is True.

Comment: @ambrishdhaka - If there are only `True` and `False` you can omit it. Try if same output.